# why it does not compile issue

Tags: java, compilation

A part of my project I have a class named Team and a class Game. When I try to compile the following code, these errors are occurred.

```
Player allPlayers[] = new Player[10];
```

> Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

```
public void addPlayer(Player p)
```

> Syntax error on token ")", ; expected after this token
>   Syntax error on token "(", ; expected after this token
>
> and the same errors for all the methods declarations

Source code of class team

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Team 
{
 rounds = 0;
private static final int cPlayers = 5; //Arithmos pektwn se kathe omada
//Constructor
public Game() { 
............
}
```

Does it have to do anything with this?

Comment: Whew. Format your code, this is unreadable. And make a [mcve]? Read that page carefully. It'll most likely solve your problem.

Comment: You cannot create `allPlayers[n] = new Forward();` outside of a method (well, you could in a static initializer, but don't go there). Move those into a constructor or an init method that is then called somewhere.

Comment: @KevinO There are also *initializer blocks*; they're copied into *every* constructor.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, a valid augmentation to the comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only place this code in a code block.  What you can do is

```
Player allPlayers[] = new Player[10]; 
{
allPlayers[0] = new Forward();
allPlayers[1] = new Forward();
allPlayers[2] = new Forward();
allPlayers[3] = new Defender();
allPlayers[4] = new Defender();
}
```

Or you can do

```
Player[] allPlayers = { new Forward(), new Forward(), new Forward(),
                        new Defender(), new Defender(),
                        null, null, null, null, null };
```